# Changing a “static” slider into a dynamic, easily changeable one

Tags: jquery, plugins, slider, wordpress

I'm currently having a "static" slider for a wordpress theme, which I want to change into a dynamic one. That means that I currently always have to work around in the code to add new slides, content and so on for the slider. But I want to change it, that I can easily change it in the wordpress dashboard, in form of a plugin. My programming skills are not good enough yet to write an own plugin for that, especially not under time pressure like I have.

So is there a plugin to change a static slider to a dynamic one? Or is there a Slider Plugin where I can edit all the HTML Markup and paste in mine?

So far I've tried WP Slider Plugin, which does not work like I'd need it. Any help is appreciated,

PS: My slider consists out of an Image, The Navigation where all the slides are, and an Information box left of it which displays text from the current slide.

PPS: Basically I'd need a form/meta-fields where I can add these things (Backgroundimage, Slide, Slide-Title, Slide Infotext with HTML Markup) and it would add it to the slider... but that's over my current knwoledge.

EDIT: Okay, I tried using: http://www.armagost.com/blog/developing-a-content-slider-with-custom-post-types/ 
But since that one has a whole different structure, I tried this. It didn't work, and I'm not sure why. I'm using the Slides from WordPress, and tried to query them and query then the post by ID, also try to query the Title and the thumbnail. Doesn't work. Any hints from anyone? Desperated.

```
    <div id="intro">
<div id="featured" >
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
<li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-1"><a href="#fragment-1"><?php echo get_the_title($1); ?> </a></li>
<li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-2"><a href="#fragment-2"><?php echo get_the_title($2); ?></a></li>
<li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-4"><a href="#fragment-4"><?php echo get_the_title($3); ?></a></li>
<li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-5"><a href="#fragment-5"><?php echo get_the_title($4); ?></a></li>
<li class="ui-tabs-nav-item" id="nav-fragment-6"><a href="#fragment-6"><?php echo get_the_title($5); ?></a></li>
</ul>


<div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel">
<?php
$post_id = 1;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id,'post_type' => 'slide');
?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="info" >
        <?php
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?></div>
</div>

<div id="fragment-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
<?php
$post_id = 2;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id,'post_type' => 'slide');
?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="info" >
        <?php
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?></div>
</div>




<div id="fragment-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
<?php
$post_id = 3;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id,'post_type' => 'slide');
?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="info" >
        <?php
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?></div>
</div>



<div id="fragment-5" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
<?php
$post_id = 4;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id,'post_type' => 'slide');
?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="info" >
        <?php
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?></div>
</div>


<div id="fragment-6" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
    <?php
$post_id = 5;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="info" >
        <?php
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?></div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How did the WP slider plugin not work the way you wanted it to?

Comment: @msbodetti It's built up in a different way than my slider. My slider consists out of an Image, The Navigation where all the slides are, and an Information box left of it which displays text from the current slide.

Comment: Maybe you should put that in your question above so people will know what plugin you are looking for :)

Comment: Basically I'd need a form/meta-fields where I can add these things (Backgroundimage, Slide, Slide-Title, Slide Infotext with HTML Markup) and it would add it to the slider... but that's over my current knwoledge.

Answer (score 2):

Well, ofcruse the best way to do it is to write your own code, so you can have exactly what you want. but in you situation, i would advis just to download new plug in and make all the changes via the admin panel. I looked up for some sliders, just choose what ever you like [on this link.](http://speckyboy.com/2013/06/06/the-best-free-responsive-sliders-plugins-for-wordpress/)

Comment: Sorry, that didn't really help. Mainly because I guess I'm too stupid to rip apart plugins and rewrite them. Now, I started to use this here: http://www.armagost.com/blog/developing-a-content-slider-with-custom-post-types/ And tried around, but it doesnt work. Will put up the code up there.